# How to initialize RabbitMQ consumer using pika and connexion

Tags: python, pika, connexion

I'm trying to set up a Python microservice that receives messages through RabbitMQ, while having a `/health` REST endpoint for the Kubernetes healthcheck. I'm using [pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for the RabbitMQ consumer, and [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the REST endpoint.

However, when I start the RabbitMQ consumer in `main()` the connexion app wont start.

python-app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika, sys, os, connexion
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='./')

def main():
    # Connection
    ...
    # Exchange and queues
    ...

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        ...

    channel.basic_consume(queue='pg-python', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages.')
    channel.start_consuming()
    app.run(port=8080, use_reloader=False)

@app.route('/api/v1/health', methods=['GET'])
def return_health():
    message = {'status':'Healthy! <3'}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

Output:

```
[*] Waiting for messages.
```

How can I properly initialize both components? Do I need to use threads?

Comment: The problem is that pika is blocking, so you never reach the app.run. I created an example on how this could work with flask, and it should work for connexion too.
https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/main/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it a requirement to have http health check? Would not a python command line process with pika do the job? The health check is not doing much anyway (e.g. if your consumer thread gets blocked and unresponsive, it will still return healthy, or not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by initializing the RabbitMQ consumer in a separate thread:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika, sys, os, threading
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

def start_rmq_connection():
    # Connection
    ...
    # Exchange and queues
    ...

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        ...

    channel.basic_consume(queue='pg-python', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
    print(' [*] Waiting for messages.')
    channel.start_consuming()

@app.route('/api/v1/health', methods=['GET'])
def return_health():
    message = {'status':'Healthy! <3'}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=start_rmq_connection)
        thread_1.start()
        thread_1.join(0)
        app.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```